# why Meteor kadira FlowRouter url end with "?"

Tags: meteor, flow-router, meteor-react

Why do my url end with a ? with I call `FlowRouter.go(/score/ + this.props.courseId)` it shouldnt end with a ?. I am using react with meteor.

`http://localhost:3000/score/k5QKvkFet5wteAg2r?` <----question mark?

shown in my debug

```
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/score/k5QKvkFet5wteAg2r?
```

router.jsx

```
FlowRouter.route("/score/:courseId/", {
    name: "Score",
    action (params) {
        renderMainLayoutWith(<Score courseId={params.courseId}/>)
    }
})
```

Comment: please post your route code also.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed posted ans i am using react with meteor

Comment: ahh, it's react. i have not much experience in react flow router.It might be a cause for react. not sure though. Try omitting last `/` of your route. I generally don't give the last slash and in blaze it works for me.